# Segmentation fault when loading data into a struct array C

Tags: c, windows, segmentation-fault

I'm getting a segmentation fault when I try to read a value from the file and load the data into the struct vector. The line with the first occurrence of the segmentation fault is indicated in the code. I'm running it on a Windows machine. I would appreciate any help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct box
{
    int height, width, depth, value, rotation;
} Box;


int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{

    FILE *in;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
    int l=0;
    int value;
    int n_boxes;
    int max_height;
    Box *boxes = (Box*) malloc(sizeof(Box)*2*n_boxes);

    in = fopen("stk10.data", "r");

    if(in == NULL)
        printf("Couldn't open the file\n");
    else
    {
        while( (fscanf(in, "%d", &value))!=EOF )
        {
            if(i==0)
                n_boxes= value;
            if(i==1)
                max_height = value;
            if(i>=2 && i<n_boxes+2)
            {
                boxes[j].value = value; //segmentation fault here
                j++;
            }
            if(i>=n_boxes+2)
            {
                if(k%3==0)
                    boxes[l].width = value;
                if(k%3==1)
                    boxes[l].height = value;
                if(k%3==2)
                    boxes[l].depth = value;
                boxes[l].rotation = 1;
                k++;
                if(k%3==0)
                    l++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    free(boxes);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `n_boxes` is uninitialized when you use it to `malloc` your `Box` array.

Comment: The `malloc()` call for `boxes` needs to go after you get the value for `n_boxes`.

Comment: "C" and "vector" live uneasily together in one sentence/question.

Comment: @tdcc it is a new feature in the C18. It's called mind reading variable. It knows its value before you enter int.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurred because n_boxes was uninitialized. I read n_boxes outside the loop and called the malloc function after reading n_boxes as indicated in the comment section.